# phpMyAdmin privileges are not being set

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have given a user only SELECT privileges, yet the insert, copy and drop options are visible and can be selected.

I cannot seem to figure out what I am missing.

From the root, it shows this:
[image]

But when i log in through that user acount, i see this:

[image]

Comment: Did you refresh all privileges after the change?

Comment: I restarted the service mysqld, would that refresh the privileges?

Comment: I don't think it does (I may be wrong). There's a small link at the bottom of the privileges page in phpMyAdmin titled `Reload the privileges'.

Comment: This is extremely misleading. I tried deleting one of the tables. And only after confirming the delete did it say the user was denied.  Although, It would really help if the options did not show up in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extremely misleading. I tried deleting one of the tables. And only after confirming the delete did it say the user was denied. Although, It would really help if the options did not show up in the first place.
Basically, the options for editing the table will still be present, however, only when the user confirms that he/she wants to make the change will the "denied" message appear